# scikit-learn: general question about parallel computing

Tags: scikit-learn

I would like to use `sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV()` on multiple processors in parallel. This is the first time I will do this, but my initial tests show that it seems to be working.

I am trying to understand [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) part of the documentation:

> `n_jobs` : int, default 1
>
> > Number of jobs to run in parallel.
>
> `pre_dispatch` : int, or string, optional
>
> > Controls the number of jobs that get dispatched during parallel
> >     execution. Reducing this number can be useful to avoid an explosion of
> >     memory consumption when more jobs get dispatched than CPUs can
> >     process. This parameter can be:
> >
> > > None, in which case all the jobs are immediately created and
> > >       spawned. Use this for lightweight and fast-running jobs, to avoid
> > >       delays due to on-demand spawning of the jobs   An int, giving the
> > >       exact number of total jobs that are spawned   A string, giving an
> > >       expression as a function of n_jobs, as in ‘2*n_jobs’

Can someone break this down for me? I'm having trouble understanding the difference between `n_jobs` and `pre_dispatch`. If I set `n_jobs = 5` and `pre-dispatch=2`, how is this different from just setting `n_jobs=2`?

Answer (score 17):

Suppose you are using `GridSearchCV` for KNN with parameters' grid: `k=[1,2,3,4,5, ... 1000]`.

Even when you set `n_jobs=2`, `GridSearchCV` will *first* create 1000 jobs, each with one choice of your `k`, also making 1000 copies of your data (possibly blowing up your memory if your data is big), then sending those 1000 jobs to 2 CPUs (most jobs will be pending of course).

`GridSearchCV` doesn't just spawn 2 jobs for 2 CPUs because the process of spawing jobs on-demand is expensive. It directly spawns equal amount of jobs as parameter combinations you have (1000 in this case).

In this sense, the wording `n_jobs` might be misleading. Now, using `pre_dispatch` you can set how many *pre-dispatched* jobs you want to spawn.

Answer (score 2):

[Source](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV.html)

> If n_jobs was set to a value higher than one, the data is copied for each parameter setting(and not n_jobs times). This is done for efficiency reasons if individual jobs take very little time, but may raise errors if the dataset is large and not enough memory is available. A workaround in this case is to set pre_dispatch. Then, the memory is copied only pre_dispatch many times. A reasonable value for pre_dispatch is 2 * n_jobs.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I don't understand what happens when 5 processes have to share 2 data "chunks"?

Comment: `pre_dispatch` essentially controls the number of 'batches' of tasks sent.